# What makes "AAA" games so special?

Tags: game-design

What makes a "AAA" game. and its engine and technology, so special?
Why are they so hard to make, and take so long to make?  Why can't an average basement dweller write a game or engine with graphics that are just as good or realistic?

Take *"Crysis"* or *"Battlefield 3"*, for example; if someone knew the techniques, algorithms, and everything else needed, what would stop them?

Comment: "what would stop them?" Money, time, crew, maybe more. Otherwise, nothing, in fact.

Comment: Time. Budget. The need to eat, sleep, bathe, and exercise.

Comment: This question is pretty discussion-oriented and is probably better suited for the chat.

Comment: Note that I have voted to close this question as a duplicate; I think this is simply the best way to *retain* this question; but it has general issues of being too broad. I am also unsure of what to tag it - it was using [tag:engine]; but this tag has been blacklisted - in part because questions specific to general game engines are too broad for our scope.

Answer (score 8):

1) **Creating Assets** What "looks good" has a lot to do with a combination of technical features + artwork. Once you implement a i.e. a displacement map shader, you need to find a good artist and provide him with the tools to generate said displacement map. For an AAA game, the team involved in creating the assets is huge.

2) **Performance and resource budgeting** It's much easier to make a feature that runs a demo scene at 60fps on your beefy development box than to run the maximal scene in the game at 60fps on your minimum specs (and consoles)

3) **Time and Effort** I'm not a professional, and I have no numbers for AAA games, but here's a useful number: http://www.ohloh.net/p/doom3/estimated_cost  Doom 3. 174 person-years.

4) **Nothing, really?** If you're just looking to implement cool graphics features, go ahead and whip a tech demo together! I saw this video a while back: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9N-kgCqy2xs or just youtube for random Unity3D or XNA demos or follow indie studios like [Wolfire](http://www.wolfire.com/)and you'll see that people outside the AAA game world are putting together great things.